# How to call function in a screen from another screen using Actions in react native router flux

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

Hi I have 2 page in my Project .When I go from the first page to the second page (using Action), then I return to the First page with the command Action.pop() ,At this time I want to call function in first page, how can I do it?

in first page :

```
.....
BacktoFirstPage(){
    //my code
}
render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Actoin.secondPage()}>
            <Text>go to second page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
.....
```

in second page:

```
render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Actoin.pop()}>
            <Text>back to first page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

now ,  how to call BacktoFirstPage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is to pass the function you want to run as a parameter to next screen and then run it before pop the screen.

**Example**

```
....
BacktoFirstPage(){
    //my code
}
render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Actoin.secondPage({onPop: this.BacktoFirstPage.bind(this)})}>
            <Text>go to second page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
.....
```

---

```
render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ this.props.onPop(); Actoin.pop()}>
            <Text>back to first page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

**OR**

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.props.onPop();
}

render(){
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{ Actoin.pop()}>
            <Text>back to first page</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

Comment: it's true . Thank you